# how to use mount function from c?

Tags: c++, mount

I want to use mount function to implement NFS.

```
int mount(const char *source, const char *target,
                 const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags,
                 const void *data);
```

I can implement it by using **mount command** e.g `mount 172.16.0.144:/tmp/test /tmp/test`. But when I use the `mount()` function , it doesn't work. This is my code here .

```
#include<sys/mount.h> 
#include<iostream>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    const char* srcPath = "/tmp/watchman";
    const char* targetPath = "172.16.0.144:/tmp/watchman";
    if (argc == 3) {
        srcPath = argv[1];
        targetPath = argv[2];
        cerr << "reset the src && target path\n";
    } else {
        if (argc != 1) {
            cerr << "wrong input argument!\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cerr << "srcPath = " << srcPath << endl;
    cerr << "target = " << targetPath << endl;
    int ret_val = mount(srcPath, targetPath, "", MS_SHARED, "");
    if (ret_val == 0) {
        cerr << "mount succeed\n";
        string filename = string(srcPath) + "/" + "tmp.txt";
        fstream fin(filename.c_str(), ios::out);
        fin << "there is a write test from client\n";
        fin.close();
        ret_val = umount(srcPath);
        if (ret_val == 0) {
            cerr << "umount succeed \n";
        } else {
            cerr << "umount failed \n";
            printf("%s/n", strerror(errno));
        }
    } else {
        cout<<"ret_val = "<<ret_val<<endl;
        cerr << "mount failed \n";
        cerr << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It printf mount failed,No such file or directory. anyone can help me? please !!!

Comment: Use correct tags. This is C++, not C.

Answer (score 2):

If you [read the `mount` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) you will see that

> **`mount()`** attaches the filesystem specified by `source` (which is often a pathname referring to a device, but can also be the pathname of a directory or file, or a dummy string) to the location (a directory or file) specified by the pathname in `target`.

You have switched the source and target in your application.

Comment: I try it, but it still doesn't work. can you give me a example for that ? I am very confused it.

Comment: @CloriaD Do the directory `/tmp/watchman` exist? It must exist before you can use it as a target for mount.

Comment: yes , of course exist. Both in NFS server and local the /tmp/watchman folder is exist. So do you have the example can run and have a good result ?  Help me please.

Comment: @CloriaD The "example" you ask for is what you have now, but with `srcPath` and `targetPath ` switched.

Comment: @CloriaD Oh, and maybe try to provide a filesystem type? Like `"nfs"`? And *no* mount flag.